# How to get image position in Pygame

Tags: python, image, drag-and-drop, pygame

I am coding for a mouse drag and drop effect on images. Meanwhile, I want to take record of the upper-left point of image each time I dragged and dropped it, are there any ways to get it?

Comment: What do you mean by drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

What methods are you using to draw the images? It's hard to answer this question without that.

If you aren't already doing this, you could use a class to hold data about your image, such as position and geometry.

Answer (score 1):

If you derive your classes from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` , you can get the position by `guy.rect`. Depending on if you want center, or toplef, or the full rect:

`guy.rect.topleft` or `guy.rect.center` or `guy.rect`